# append two void* pointers

Tags: c, pointers, void

Is there a way to append 2 void* ptr?  Each is an array of chars:

For example:

```
void * ptr;
ptr = malloc(3);
read(0, ptr, 3);

void * rtr;
rtr = malloc(3);
read (0, rtr, 3);

/*how to add ptr and rtr??*/
```

Thank you!

*EDIT: YES, I would like to add the contents together.
In actuality this is more of how my code works:

```
void *ptr;
ptr = malloc(3);
read(0, ptr, 3);

void *rtr;
rtr = malloc(1);
int reader;
reader=read(0, rtr, 1);
int i=1;
while(reader!=0){
  /* append contents of rtr to ptr somehow?? */
  i++;
  rtr = realloc(rtr, i);
  reader=read(0, rtr, 1);
}
```

I'm reading from a file.  And the file might change, I have to append byte-by-byte if the file changes.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do? Add the 2 addresses together? Or add the contents?

Comment: Why won't you use char* instead of void* ?

Comment: Not unless you know how big they are, and it looks like you don't.  (Each could be between 0 and 3 bytes, depending.)

Comment: What is that for? What are You trying to achieve?

Comment: the thing is, your void pointer must point to a specific block of memory that is either allocated on the stack or heap. Reading into an uninitialized pointer will cause havoc, typically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't really have an answer for the way you worded it, but I'll try...

You must allocate a block of memory first, using malloc(). Then, your void pointer would point to that. That block would have a definite size. The second block conforms to the same concepts, and has a definite size.

In order to append the second to the first, the first block should have been allocated with enough extra space to append the second block's contents. You would then use memcpy() to copy the bytes from the second block to the first block. You would need to use a cast to a byte pointer to specify the offset into the first block.

((unsigned char *)(ptr) + ptr_alloced_bytes) would be the offset into the first block to the end of the first copied data, where ptr_alloced_bytes is the number of bytes read by the first operation.

Otherwise you would need to allocate a new block that is large enough to hold both blocks, then copy them both using memcpy().

Comment: YES, I'm sorry, I did have an allocate memory/reallocate function. Totally forgot to put that in...will update the post.  In the meantime, I will try using memcpy.  Thank you,

Comment: I'm trying to figure out memcpy, but even if i allocated a new block that's large enough to hold both blocks, can I use it to append?  Or will source to destination simply overwrite?

Comment: Your welcome... but I would suggest using a different method. I'd assume you're learning C. Might I suggest a book, C in 21 days by SAMS PUBLISHING. A good online tutorial is Coranado Enterprizes C tutorial.

Comment: memcpy will overwrite if you don't specify an offset. It's called pointer arithmetic. You supply the first pointer, an addition sign, and the offset into the buffer to copy to. But you must cast to unsigned char * because void * has no byte size.